# jQuery into Wordpress functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have this jQuery script I was using in Unbounce and now need to use it on a Wordpress page. I'm assuming I'll need this to go in the child theme functions file, but I know it's missing some php. I'm still a little new to this and could use a little guidance.

Thank you!

```js
jQuery(function($){
    var billed={
        'monthly': 'https://',
        'annually': 'https://'
    };
    
    $.submit_button=$('#plan_button');
    $.billed_buttons=$('.billed-monthly, .billed-annually');
    $.billed_buttons
    .on('click',function(){
        var $img=$(this), is_monthly=$img.attr('class').indexOf('billed-monthly')>=0, url=billed[is_monthly?'monthly':'annually'];
        
        if(url){
            $.billed_buttons.removeClass('active');
            $img.addClass('active');
            $.submit_button.attr('href',url);
        }
      
        return !1;
    })
    .filter('.billed-annually')
    .trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your js by adding a 'wp_enqueue_script' action in your theme's functions.php and register your js script file:

```
function template_files() 
{    
    // Name of your script should be unique
    wp_enqueue_script('name-for-your-script', 'path/to/your/js/file/your_script.js');
}

add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "template_files");
```